# Clearing duplicates Excel Macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I have a column that may contain duplicate values. The cell that will contain duplicates corresponds to the data in that row. My problem is that the duplicate values may be the same but the corresponding data in that row may be different. Thus, I can not have it delete the duplicates if the corresponding data is different. This is the code I have currently but it will clear unnecessary duplicates. (Replace with zero)
    [image]

```
For i = M To 2 Step -1
    Set rlook = Range(Cells(i - 1, "D"), Cells(2, 4))
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rlook, Cells(i, "D")) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "D").clear
    End If
Next i
```

I have attached a snapshot of what the final result should look like. Data will start at "A7" till last row used. The final result is in columns "G:J".

Thanks

Comment: This needs to be done in VBA. If I record it I will have to select two rows check for duplicates then select the next two rows check for duplicates and so on.. I want it automated to where it will just check the first two row and move on till the next two rows as the data will be a couple hundred rows long.

Comment: Is it safe to assume your data is already sorted like you show in the picture? And you just want to remove the value in the "Amount" column, if the `#`, `Source`, and `LastName` are the same in the current row and the one below?

Comment: Why not aggregate the amount for non-duplicates and discard duplicate amounts?

Comment: `range("g7").formula="=A7":range("h7").formula="=IF(h8=h7,a7,"")"` filled down? or just the formula?

Comment: Correct this is what the data will look like once sorted. Columns "A:D" is the actual data set. Columns "G:J" is what I want the final result to look like. And i'm not sure I am following your question in regards to filled down or formula? I believe it just needs to be filled down from "D7" till last row used as there is more to the process after these duplicates are removed.

Comment: Why not combine all data fields into a composit key and then delete the duplicates?

Comment: What would be the process to do this?

Comment: in cell "E7" add formula: =CONCATINATE(A7, B7, C7, D7)

Then fill it down for all records. It will create a key that will be unique if data within the row is different. If it's the same, the keys will be identical, and you can just delete the duplicates.

Comment: I just tried it and im getting "#NAME?" down all the rows.

Comment: What is the point of having the same information but zero amount? I think I'd just use the Advanced Filter and click UNIQUE values, if you do not require Column A, B, C repeated with zero Amount.

Comment: Because this is what I need done. As there is a row that will be inserted and a formula applied to all the duplicates in column "A" and only one value is needed from column "D" that corresponds to A.